# Implementing Price Tiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce

I am curious if there are any common patterns for partitioning a web application by features? An example would be to sell at multiple price tiers.

What I am asking is there a common development pattern to partition features within an application

Comment: Can you be more specific?  For example, I don't see how price tiers require any specific database partitioning, just logic to determine the price for which a certain customer qualifies.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say anything about database partitioning. What I asking is there a common development pattern for partition features within an application. A reason to do this might be to implement Price Tiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a pattern that I know of. One way of implementing what you want would be to give users roles dependant upon what price tier they have chosen and to then have role checking on specific features/views. Almost like a form of access control list, which is controlled by their purchased package.

Comment: Thanks, that was my initial thought. I was hoping for some super awesome sophisticated pattern for handling this at the model/controller level.